# How to parse a string that begins and ends with a specific character

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am trying to parse the following string with Java:

> s_ev14=cid=extCid-1:med=extMid-2:source=google:scode=RSG00000E017:campdesc=123456789

The caveat is that the (cid,med,source,scode,campdesc), may come scrambled and in some cases they may not exist. That being said, I am looking to pick up the strings assigned to these tags.
This is what I have so far:

```
var Cid = input.substring(input.indexOf('cid=')+4,input.indexOf(':'));
```

and get an output of "extCid-1", but I am having difficulties parsing the rest of the variables since ":" is appearing on multiple spots.

Here is my full code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
                if (event.origin === "https://www.fdafadsfads.com"
                    || event.origin === "https://stage.rreasdfsd.com"
                    || event.origin === "https://stage-www.vderere.com"
                    || event.origin === "https://m.vereasre.com") { 
                    /* only accept messages from appropriate senders */
                    console.log('Supported origin: ' + event.origin); // comment later
                } else {
                    console.log('Unsupported orgin: ' + event.origin);  // comment later  
                    return;
                }
    //s_ev14=cid=extCid-1:med=extMid-2:source=google:scode=RSG00000E017:campdesc=123456789
                console.log("raw event.data: " + event.data);


                //Removes s_ev14 from the string
                //cid=extCid-1:med=extMid-2:source=google:scode=RSG00000E017:campdesc=123456789
                var SlicedData = event.data.slice(7);
                console.log("Sliced event data: " + SlicedData);


                const input = SlicedData; 

                const dictionary = {
                    cid: '',
                    med: '',
                    source: '',
                    scode: '',
                    campdesc: ''
                }

                const result = 
                    input.split(":")
                         .map(s => s.split("="))
                         .filter(o => !!o[1])
                         .reduce((dictionary, o) => {
                         dictionary[o[0]] = o[1]
                         return dictionary
                         }, dictionary)

                    const cid1 = result['cid']
                    const med1 = result['med']
                    const source1 = result['source']
                    const scode1 = result['scode']
                    const campdesc1 = result['campdesc']

console.log("Cid1: " + cid1);
            console.log("Med1: " + med1);
            console.log("Source1: " + source1);
            console.log("Scode1: " + scode1);
            console.log("Campdesc1: " + campdesc1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: OP tagged `Java` instead of `JavaScript`. As the `var` syntax is the same, we all got confused.

An approach using a `Stream` might be

```
final String input = "s_ev14=cid=extCid-1:med=extMid-2:source=google:scode=RSG00000E017:campdesc=123456789";
final Map<String, String> attributes =
        Stream.of(input.substring(7).split(":"))
              .map(s -> s.split("=", 2))
              .filter(o -> o.length > 1)  // If you don't want empty values
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o[0], o -> o[1]));
```

Output

```
{scode=RSG00000E017, campdesc=123456789, source=google, med=extMid-2, cid=extCid-1}
```

---

If what you need to do is assign each value to a series of variables, just

```
final var cid = attributes.get("cid");
final var med = attributes.get("med");
final var source = attributes.get("source");
final var campdesc = attributes.get("campdesc");
```

That's using `Java 10`+ syntax, which seems you're using too.

---

**For the `JavaScript` version**

```
const input = "cid=extCid-1:med=extMid-2:source=:scode=RSG00000E017:campdesc=123456789"

// Default values
const dictionary = {
  cid: '',
  med: '',
  source: '',
  code: '',
  campdesc: ''
}

const result = 
    input.split(":")     // <-- Change the separator to & if needed
         .map(s => s.split("="))
         .filter(o => !!o[1])
         .reduce((dictionary, o) => {
            dictionary[o[0]] = o[1]
            return dictionary
         }, dictionary)  // <-- Default values as starting point

const cid = result['cid']
const med = result['med']
const source = result['source']
const code = result['code']
const campdesc = result['campdesc']
```

Output

```
{cid: "extCid-1", med: "extMid-2", scode: "RSG00000E017", campdesc: "123456789"}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Much appreciated. This is great, but what I would like to do is assign each string to a designated variable. For example, the value of "med" string should be assigned to a med variable, so that I can use it to do a search on that string in my database. Would you happen to have any guidance?

Comment: @IvoDimov Are these variables contained in a class? If they are, could you post that class?

Comment: @IvoDimov see updated answer. Is this what you need?

Comment: Thank you again. I am actually trying to use Java code in my Salesforce VisualForce page. I am attempting to read an url and parse each variable, so that then I can use in a SOQL (SQL) search in my Salesforce database. This seems to be what I need, but when I run it, is is erorring out in my browser developer console. I will post my current code

Comment: @IvoDimov I'm not a Salesforce user, so I cannot be sure. Could you maybe update your question with more details and your current code?

Comment: I completely understand, and thank you for trying to help me. I just a portion of my with your recommendation. I originally had the code working by picking the strings based on their order, but since the order of the tags can change, my code will fails. That is why I was attempting to use substring with indexof() but the multiple ' : ' is throwing it off.

Comment: @IvoDimov the problem is you're on JavaScript here, not on Java. I'll try to replicate the same in JavaScript

Comment: @IvoDimov I updated the question with the JavaScript version.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much @LppEdd !!!.
I tried your code and this seems to be working as expected. I moved the different tags in different order and all is working as expected. The one problem I have noticed when I was testing all scenarios, is that if I remove from the string one of the following strings, or set as blank (cid, med, or source), then for the output I get is 'Undefined' for all. I get raw event.data: s_ev14=null in my log. I would expect all values to be populated, but the one that is missing. This seems to be working if I remove (campdesc, or scode).

Comment: @IvoDimov could you paste here an example of "mangled" string?

Comment: Sure Thing
Missing 'med': cid=extCid-1&source=google&scode=RSG00000E017&campdesc=123456789
Missing 'cid': med=extMid-2&source=google&scode=RSG00000E017&campdesc=123456789
No Value for 'cid': cid=&med=extMid-2&source=google&scode=RSG00000E017&campdesc=123456789

Comment: @IvoDimov and you would like to have `med` and `cid` as empty strings, right?

Comment: Any of these tags could be missing, or set to no value  (cid, med,scode, source, campdesc). The error I am having is that if cid, or med, or source are missing or blank, then all of them are set as undefined. I would expect only if one of the value is blank or missing, but the rest are populated, then the other values should still be populated.

Comment: @IvoDimov see updated answer. Should work as you described.

Comment: Thank you again. I am experiencing  about the same behavior. If 'cid' is missing or blank, then all other tags are set as blank even though they get populated. I think this may not be related to this code. This string usually comes as part of an URL, which is what I am trying to parse. If you look at my code on the top, I noticed that in this scenario I get the following in my console.log when (cid,med, source) are missing or blank:
raw event.data: null

Comment: @IvoDimov my code works because I tested it many times. Could you post your current code so I can give a look to it?

Comment: @IvoDimov I tested my code here https://playcode.io/262487?tabs=console&script.js&output

Comment: I just updated my code. I would agree that it should work, and this must be related to something else. I think it is because Java is embeded into a web form, and may be that is why
console.log("raw event.data: " + event.data); 
is returning null

Comment: @IvoDimov if `event.data` is `null`, then I don't know what else do to, because I don't know the framework.

Comment: Thank you so much @LppEdd!!! I think what you have helped me with is definitely solving what I am trying to do. Thank you again for going above and beyond in helping me out. Much Appreciated !!!

Comment: Hi @LppEdd, I just hit another scenario, and was wondering if I can ask you about it. I just noticed that I may receive the whole string more than once, and I have to pick up the latest values for each parameter:
cid=extCid-5:med=extMid-2:source=google:scode=RSG00000E017:campdesc=123456789|cid=extCid-6:med=extMid-6:source=mine:scode=R7:campdesc=1
Currently the code is picking up the first occurrences for the tags like cid = extCID-5, but I am looking to pick cid=extCid-6 instead. Could you help me solve for that? I did have multiple unsuccessful attempts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.split(":")` method to split all the tokens in the given string and then use `String.startsWith` and `String.endsWith` methods to actually get values for individual tokens.

Comment: Look at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression:

```
String s = "s_ev14=cid=extCid-1:med=extMid-2:source=google:scode=RSG00000E017:campdesc=123456789";

Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=([^:=]+)(?=:|$)").matcher(s); m.find(); )
    map.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
campdesc=123456789
cid=extCid-1
med=extMid-2
scode=RSG00000E017
source=google
```

**UPDATE**

Once parsed to `Map`, they are easy to extract to variables:

```
String cid = map.get('cid');
String med = map.get('med');
String source = map.get('source');
String scode = map.get('scode');
String campdesc = map.get('campdesc');
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am essentially trying to identify each tag and assign it to a designated variable, so that I can use it in a query string.